# Paypal adaptive payment fee

Tags: paypal, split, payment

I've been research on this topic without relevant information. The question is, if you split a payment using Adaptive Payment API (Parallel payment) to Seller A and Seller B, would each of them need to pay the 30cents one time fee, in addition to the 1.9-2.9% commission? Put it mathematically:

Buyer pays $10.00 to MyGig.com -
MyGig will split into 2 payments, $5.00 to itself for hosting, and $5.00 to the actual contractor.
Does MyGig pay 30cents + 2.9% (of the $5.00) as a total fee? Does the contractor also pay 30cents + 2.9% (of the $5.00) as a total fee? If this is the case, how do you avoid the 30cents to be applied twice? Does chained payment circumvent that problem?